# How to indicate what the return type is going to be when there are multiple types possible in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to write types around an Axios API client but don't understand the right way to tell the compiler which return type I'm expecting.

A simplified example:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

interface BaseApiResponse extends AxiosResponse { }

interface ApiCollectionResponse<T> extends BaseApiResponse {
    data: T[]
    meta: {
        totalCount: number
        totalPages: number
    }
}

interface ApiResourceResponse<T> extends BaseApiResponse {
    data: T
}

type ApiResponse<T> = ApiCollectionResponse<T> | ApiResourceResponse<T>

const apiAction = <T>(url: string, onSuccess: (response: ApiResponse<T>) => void) => {
    axios
        .request({ url })
        .then(({ data }) => {
            onSuccess(data)
        })
}

interface User {
    name: string
}

const loadUsers = () => 
    apiAction<User>('/users', (data) => alert(data.meta.totalCount))
```

The response data can either be a `ApiCollectionResponse` or a `ApiResourceResponse`. The compiler rightfully complains that the property `meta` doesn't exist on the `ApiResourceResponse` interface.

How would I express that this call to `apiAction` will result in a `ApiCollectionResponse` return value?

Comment: I don't think you're able to do what you want to do. Why not just define two functions, `apiResourceAction` and `apiCollectionAction`?

Comment: I'm very new to TypeScript but it seems like a code smell to define two identical functions just to get correct types. Personally, I think @ford04's second suggestion around "function overloads" looks to be more scalable.

Comment: Agreed, I learnt about function overloads from their answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not matter much where you typecast the fetched data, as long as everything is encapsulated in the same API/axios module. For the consuming module, just `loadUsers` or other exported methods would be important.

You could do one of the following:

1.) Define explicit methods `apiActionUsers`, `apiActionXXX` etc. (easiest, if you ask me):

```
function apiActionUsers() {
  apiAction<User>("/users", data =>
    alert((data as ApiCollectionResponse<User>).meta.totalCount)
  )
}
```

Instead of raw casting, you may also define a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) instead to distinguish the possible types of `ApiResponse`.

2.) Use [function overloards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
type ApiAction = {
  <T>(
    url: "/users",
    onSuccess: (response: ApiCollectionResponse<T>) => void
  ): void
  <T>(
    url: "/other-resource",
    onSuccess: (response: ApiResourceResponse<T>) => void
  ): void
}

const apiAction: ApiAction = (
  url: string,
  onSuccess: (response: any) => void
) => {
  axios.request({ url }).then(onSuccess)
}

// works!
apiAction<User>("/users", data => alert(data.meta.totalCount))
```

Have a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZwDRwN5wIIroBKApmpAHZolwC+cAZlBCHAETKppsCwAUP2AUYJKAwQBjGgCEE1PGGClyEKjRJIRFACZp8hNMsrUctfoOGjxU-IoDCEADaOSEmKgpHV1ADwAVAD44DS1dOFl5RS81HH44OG0EGAQALjg-AG0AXTi4EBJktOxc+JgIZMcHAFdhNIoqkAAjURK4MoqABQQAczI6huaoXLM+EYsRMUkaBSUyCCqoKWjfQODNEh09CJIZ5ZpivnjEwvT+Mb4YAE8waaiyYxJ-IIBeW2AHZ1d3VT2nuAAfN7KeaLEi-QLmC7XW7APBuDxwV4HeJPAAUrQWjjSbAA9FVqFBuBhWqoAMpVCRSNBoNKoqD3bwkNIzD4ueE-BlqJ4ASkRQQAbhBgNpcty0oLhbk0RioFj2DjygALUQAWnpaBBUjYxMO8TgZIpVJpcDpnOozLuGoWSzNj0CvOeAqFIt1YrgEpd5wk3ngCEUcO+FAtsPZFERJtymLSaBgUCE3R18QNlLIxtNKjUaQQFEuDqdkr4edius46AAdPSAI5VMgwVG4TF0bllmDKiio5NG7lnSFCCbWGgAVQJxfiFAQ+WjsfjPYEfG9VHgjggCG0w9EeleqLzuT9IcDPnXUACqNx+I32oSSQQfMQLlgqOOCDL+WSLfKCEq82E3O7fCAA) for a sample with function overloads.